# AD GUI shows properties that PowerShell returns empty

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I want to get a list of all AD Users and their creation time and last logon time. First I used the *Active Diretory Users and Computers* app and activated the *Advanced Features*. In the *Attribute Editor* I can see the properties are called `LastLogon` and `WhenCreated`.
So I did this:

```
$allUsers = Get-ADUser  -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName,LastLogon,WhenCreated
$allUsers   | select SamAccountName,LastLogon,WhenCreated
```

However `LastLogon`and `WhenCreated` are only filled for 13 of 500 Users. In the *Attribute Editor* these values are filled for a lot more...
When I query one user only that has these values in the *Attribute Editor* with `Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties *`  I see that the attributes are called `LastLogonDate`and `Created` (values are shown empty).
So I searched for those attributes:

```
$allUsers2= Get-ADUser  -Filter * -Properties SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,Created
$allUsers2   | select SamAccountName,LastLogonDate,Created
```

Then again those 13 have the info the rest doesn't.
Has anyone an idea how I get those values? (I am going to export them with `Export-CSV` so another way to get those in Excel is ok, too )

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but what if you use the `-Server` switch on Get-ADUser and have it query the same Domain Controller you are currently connected to with Active Diretory Users and Computers. It may be that you are asking for properties that have not yet been synchronized (especially the lastLogon time stamp which I believe is synced only once every 14 days unless you have specified a different value for the `ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval` attribute on the domain default naming context.)

Comment: @Theo Tried it with the same result. But I am executing this code on the DC. Most of the Users have been created in the last 3 years and I know that there are a lot of users that haven't logged in for a couple of month....

Comment: Seems weird to me that you are seeing dates in ADUC, but PowerShell is unable to fetch them.. Have you tried using different (domain Admin) credentials? 
If this is about finding stale user objects, you may want to try `Search-ADAccount -AccountInactive -DateTime ((Get-Date).AddMonths(-4).Date) -UsersOnly` to see users that haven't logged on in the last N (here 4) months.. Does that also return just a few users? What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: What do you get with `$searcher = [adsisearcher]'(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'; $searcher.FindAll()` ?

Comment: The `$Searcher` finds all of them in the same order as `Get-ADUser`.  Your search for inactive accounts provides all users beside the 13 that have a Date. (It's not just about inactives. it's about customers who don't pay bills and since when they exist ).

Comment: @Theo HA the DC got Powershell 4.0 I executed the same query from another machine that has 5.1 and that other machine somehow gets those results... Weird... If you make an answer about how obviously it is the wrong  powershell version you get some points for making me try ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested my comments as answer.

**First attempt:**

Add the `-Server` switch on `Get-ADUser` and have it query the same Domain Controller you are currently connected to with Active Directory Users and Computers. It may be that you are asking for properties that have not yet been synchronized (especially the lastLogon time stamp which I believe is synced only once every 14 days unless you have specified a different value for the ms-DS-Logon-Time-Sync-Interval attribute on the domain default naming context.)

`-->` *didn't apply because you're running this on the DC itself*

**Second attempt:**

Try ADSI as in `$searcher = [adsisearcher]'(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))'; $searcher.FindAll()`

`-->` *same results as with `Get-ADUser`; still empty values*

**Third attempt:**

Check PowerShell version(s)

`-->` *apparently the DC had PS version 4. With version 5.1 **it works***

Answer (score 2):

First, look at what properties your cmdlet has:

```
$a = Get-ADUser -server 'DomenNameTest.en' -Identity 'makarovayu' -Properties *
$a | Get-Member
```

- I recommend copying the received data into a notepad in order to copy the available field names later.

2-Let's declare an array and use the cmdlet to try to collect information on the required fields

```
$userList = Get-ADUser -server 'DomenNameTest.en' -Properties SamAccountName,Name -Filter * |
#Do not forget that the comanlet has a limitation and can fall off on timeout.See how I work with each property in [select]
Select @{Name = "SamAccountName"; Expression={$_.SamAccountName}},@{Name = "Name"; Expression={$_.Name}} |
#Uploading data to [csv]
Export-Csv -Path "D:\Users\userTest\Desktop\userList.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Default -Delimiter ';'
Remove-Variable a,userList  #Clear the variables
```

Comment: I inspected the userproperties first. When I look in the proprties > attribtue editor of a user it shows the attribute is named `whenChanged` and `lastLogon` and both are filled. When I query this user in PowerShell (`Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties * `) I see that the attribute is called `LastLogonDate` and `Created` both empty. I like that you calculate the properties for the select and that you remove the variables at the end but I am not at a point where this matters since the results are still empty...